# Methods to prove closed-form solution to series over hypergeometric functions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, hypergeometric-function

I'm trying to solve a problem in graph theory, and I've stumbled upon the sum:

\begin{equation}
T_{nlm}=\frac{1}{(\alpha+m+n)_l}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+m+l)}{\Gamma(\alpha+m+k)}\frac{(-n)_k(-l)_k}{(1/2)_k}\frac{(2k-1)!!}{2^kk!}{}_2 F_1(-k,-m;1/2;x),
\end{equation}

where $\alpha$ is positive; $n$, $l$, and $m$ are nonnegative integers; $0\leq x\leq1$; and $(a)_n$ is a Pochhammer symbol. By messing around with this sum, I'm led to believe that the closed-form solution is simply
\begin{equation}
T_{nlm}={}_3 F_2(-n,-l,-m;1/2,-\alpha-n-l-m;x),
\end{equation}
but I'm at quite a loss in trying to formally prove it. I've gone through all of the Wolfram and DLMF identities, G&R, etc., but this series doens't seem to be known. I've checked all values $0\leq n,l,m\leq10$, and the two expressions agree on all $11^3$ cases.

How are formulae like this proven generally?

Comment: Are you familiar with Chapter $8$ of Petkovsek, Wilf, and Zeilberger's _[A=B](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.pdf)_? The introduction says "Take a definite sum of the form $f(n) = \sum_k F(n,k)$ where the summand is hypergeometric in both its arguments. Does this sum have a closed form? The material of this chapter... provides a complete algorithmic solution to this problem". It's not _immediately_ clear to me that this will solve your problem (which is why I'm leaving a comment rather than an answer), but perhaps there's an answer in the bibliography for that book?

Comment: Very interesting how the final result is clearly symmetric in $(n,l,m)$, assuming it’s correct. I wouldn’t have ever guessed this to be the case looking at the initial series.

Comment: @DavidH I think the coefficient of the sum somehow has the same symmetry as the sum itself under permutations of $n,l,m$. Originally, I arrived at the 3F2 expression by computing a sum symmetric in $n,l,m$ times $(\alpha+m+n)_l$. The sum simply reduced to the definition of 3F2.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I’ve been reading through chapters 6-8, and I admit I’m not too familiar with the material. One difference that I’ve noticed is that the book’s definition of hypergeometric is that the ratio of consecutive terms is a rational function. Since the summand in this question includes a hypergeometric function with negative integral parameters, it is a polynomial in $x$, and is indeed “hypergeometric” in the language of A=B.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor The examples they give are, however, generally not polynomials themselves, so recurrences are relatively easy to find. I’m sure that my question can be solved this way, since it is claimed to be completely algorithmic, but it will take some time for me to digest. Thank you for the reference.

Comment: $-\alpha - n - l - m$ in the second formula should be $1 - \alpha - n - l - m$. From the first formula, we have
$$[x^i] T_{nlm} =
\frac {(\alpha + m)_l} {(\alpha + n + m)_l}
 \frac {(-m)_i} {\left( \frac 1 2 \right)_i} \frac 1 {i!} S_i, \\
S_i =
\sum_{k \geq 0} \frac {(-n)_k (-l)_k} {(\alpha + m)_k}
 \frac {(-k)_i} {k!} =
 \frac {(-1)^i (-n)_i (-l)_i} {(\alpha + m)_i} \sum_{k \geq 0}
  \frac {(i - n)_k (i - l)_k} {(\alpha + m + i)_k} \frac 1 {k!}$$
if $0 \leq i \leq \min(n, l, m)$ and $[x^i] T_{n l m} = 0$ otherwise. It remains to apply Gauss's theorem.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct... Where did the $(2k-1)!!/2^k$ bit from the first expression go? Also, the Pochhammer symbols within final sum in your comment should have shifted indices $k-i$. 

I, too, tried to project out the coefficients of $x^i$, but the intermediate summation over $k$ always gives a result proportional to $(0)_i$, which is just a Kronecker delta. This would seem to imply that there is only one term, which is absurd. I think I may just have an error somewhere.

Comment: @y9QQ $\frac{(2k-1)!!}{2^{k}\,(1/2)_{k}}=1$ for all nonnegative integer $k$.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you. I had skipped the factor of $(1/2)_k$ in one line of my notes.

Comment: I still don't see the equivalence of the last two lines. I'm fairly certain the ratios of each term bewteen the two sides are not one. Is there some rearrangement I'm not seeing?

Comment: @Maxim I see what you did now; after using the division formula for the Pochhammer symbols, you simply reindexed $k\rightarrow k-i$. It seems so obvious now... Thank you, and sorry I doubted you!